# Debian Disk Manager Problem

Tags: debian, disk

I have just installed Debian 8.5 Jessie on my computer and I can't find a disk manager. Then I wrote this command to terminal: `apt-get install disk-manager`. A software installed and I tried to start the software, I clicked and it wanted to root password, I wrote and software didn't start. I wonder is all of this packages safe? The software which I installed on my computer is safe? and How can I install a disk manager on Debian?

Comment: Try to start disk-manager from the Terminal. Does it show any errors?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few useful (some built-in) tools in Debian:

- `gnome-disks` (Package name `gnome-disk-utility`) "Tool to manage+configure disks"
- `Gparted` for other partitioning/formating need
- `lsblk` and `blkid` for easy display of partition/filesystem info

Comment: So, is disk-manager package safe?

Comment: @Enes: I can't say anything about the safety of `disk-manager`. Never used it before. It seems to be python-based. Perhaps your setup is missing some dependencies, and therefore has troubles starting it. What's the debug output?

Answer (score 0):

The [`disk-manager`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/disk-manager) package is safe , it's already installed on your system after runing :

`apt-get install disk-manager`

Just open the terminal and type the following command:

- KDE desktop :

  `gksu disk-manager`
- Gnome :

  `gksudo disk-manager`

Comment: So, why did it want me root password?